# ionic 3 - receive Push notifications on Ionic dont work

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

Has anyone worked with notifications on ionic 3? I'm trying to create some apps that store fcm notification, I'm trying most of the tutorials out there but nothing seems working. When I get notification and tap it, I can't get the message.

Here's some code that I've tried

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // START
      this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
        console.log(token);
        alert('token: '+token);
      });
      this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
        console.log(token);
        alert('refresh token: '+token);
      });
      this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
        alert('data: '+data);
        if(data.wasTapped){
          console.log("Received in background " + JSON.stringify(data) );
          alert("Received in background " + JSON.stringify(data) );
          this.nav.setRoot(InboxnotifPage, {data: data});
        } else {
          console.log("Received in foreground" + JSON.stringify(data) );
          alert("Received in foreground" + JSON.stringify(data) );
          this.nav.push(InboxnotifPage, {data: data});
        };
      });
      // END
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting data in notification from backend??? is your data gets `console.log` ??

Comment: can I see your console.log response?

Comment: @Bundayy ```Received in background wasTapped:true```

Comment: what is the response of `alert('data: '+data);`

Comment: @Bundayy ```wasTapped:true``` when I check ```this.fcm.onNotification()``` function in @ionic-native/fcm/index.d.ts it only have ```wasTapped: boolean;``` in there

Comment: How are you sending your notification from the server side

Comment: @BundayyOlayinka i'm sending notif from google fcm

Answer (score 0):

you have to add .plist file in your project build root to communicate with your device

```
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
                if (data.wasTapped) {
                  alert('');
                } else {
                  console.log("Received in foreground");
                  // this.presentToast("Received in foreground");
                }
              });
              this.getToken();
              this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
                this.rest.globalToken = token;
              });
            });
```

follow the original documentation and please first of all check notification from https://console.firebase.google.com then pass token to rest Api

Comment: I'm already get notif from fcm to my phone, but when I'm tapping that notification and using ```alert(JSON.stringify(data))``` that data is {}

Comment: what you wanna do with that data? do you wish to redirect any page? or what?